# findspark.init() IndexError: list index out of range error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

When running the following in a Python 3.5 Jupyter environment I get the error below. Any ideas on what is causing it?

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

Error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
last) <ipython-input-20-2ad2c7679ebc> in <module>()
      1 import findspark
----> 2 findspark.init()
      3 
      4 import pyspark

/.../anaconda/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.5/site-packages/findspark.py in init(spark_home, python_path, edit_rc, edit_profile)
    132     # add pyspark to sys.path
    133     spark_python = os.path.join(spark_home, 'python')
--> 134     py4j = glob(os.path.join(spark_python, 'lib', 'py4j-*.zip'))[0]
    135     sys.path[:0] = [spark_python, py4j]
    136 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is most likely due to the `SPARK_HOME` environment variable not being set correctly on your system. Alternatively, you can just specify it when you're initialising `findspark`, like so:

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/path/to/spark/home')
```

After that, it should all work!

Comment: This works, so thanks for solutions! Can you please also explain what these 2 lines does ?

Answer (score 9):

I was getting the same error and was able to make it work by entering the exact installation directory:

```
import findspark
# Use this
findspark.init("C:\Users\PolestarEmployee\spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6")
# Test
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
```

> Basically, it is the directory where spark was extracted. In future where ever you see `spark_home` enter the same installation directory.
>   I also tried using toree to create a kernal instead, but it is failing somehow. A kernal would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: For me, I had to use "/" instead of "\" to make it work, i.e. findspark.init("C:/Users/....."). Not sure why tho...

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the `SPARK_HOME` variable inside bash_profile. 
For me, the following command worked(in terminal):

`export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.0/libexec/"`

After this, you can use follow these commands:

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.0/libexec')
```

Comment: From the other solutions, this solution appears to be redundant. You shouldn't have to specify the path in both places.

Comment: I would have thought that, too. However, in my environment, I still have to specify the path when calling findspark.init().

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help:

i found that findspark.init() tries to find data in .\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\python\lib, but the python folder was outside the bin folder.
i simply ran findspark.init('.\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7'), without the '\bin' folder