# Set findspark.init() Permanently

Tags: python, pyspark

I have Apache Spark installed on ubuntu at this path `/home/mymachine/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7` so I have to go to python directory, located under this directory, to be able using spark OR I can use it outside python directory with help from a library called findspark, however it seems I have to always init this library like this:

```
import findspark
findspark.init("/home/mymachine/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7")
```

everytime I want to use `findspark`, which is not very effective. Is there anyway to init this library permanently?

At [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223498/findspark-init-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-error) it mentioned need to set a variable `SPARK_HOME` on .bash_profile and I did it, but no luck.

Comment: hi, I had a similar issue on OSX.  Meaning, i added SPARK_HOME to my .bash_profile and no luck.  I had to `source .bash_profile` to resolve.

Comment: Hi @bob-haffner What do you mean with ```source .bash_profile``` to resolve?

Comment: Hi HW, when you add an env var (eg SPARK_HOME) to .bash_profile you need to close and reopen your shell or do `source .bash_profile` so you can use it.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I should note that's what i do on OSX.  I'm not too familiar with ubuntu

Comment: Hi @bob-haffner, Yes, certainly. Should be work the same in Ubuntu, but this time still not working.

Comment: Notebook or script or interpreter?   And what happens when you do `os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME')` in your notebook/interpreter/script?  I'm guessing nothing

Comment: Notebook and script. It actually has respone: ```/home/mymachine/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7``` weird right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155162/discussion-between-bob-haffner-and-helloworld).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following variables to your .bashrc file

```
export SPARK_HOME=/path/2/spark/folder
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

then `source .bashrc`
If you wish run to pyspark with jupyter notebook, add these variables to .bashrc

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

again `source .bashrc`
Now if you run `pyspark` from shell, it will launch jupyter notebook server and  pyspark will be availble on python kernels.