# IndexError: list index out of range when importing findspark.init

Tags: apache-spark

I have the following error `IndexError: list index out of range` in my jupyter notebook when I try to import

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

I know the answer already exist in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223498/findspark-init-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-error), (so it is NOT a duplicate) however, when I ran `which spark-shell` the output is: `/opt/anaconda3/bin/spark-shell` which gives me the directory and so I ran:

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/opt/anaconda3/bin/spark-shell')
```

And I get the same error. How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: try `findspark.init('/opt/anaconda3/bin/')`

Comment: @GaurangShah Same error :/

Comment: @Chique_Code: Try using `whereis spark` or `locate spark` and see if they give the same location as `which spark-shell`. Also how did you install spark? Usually spark wouldn't be located in the anaconda3 directory, you can check if there is anything like `/opt/spark...`.

Answer (score 0):

It wants spark home, not an executable. You should probably have an environment variable `$SPARK_HOME`, do you have it?

If not, try to run one of these:

```
ls -la /opt/anaconda3/bin/spark-shell
readlink -f /opt/anaconda3/bin/spark-shell
```

This will show you where the actual bin folder of spark home is. You just use part of that path int the init.

I think that if you set the `SPARK_HOME` later on, find spark runs without the need for the path specified.